# How to delete history in switcher tabs using PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm and so far I really like it.

The last thing I'd like to have is an updated tab manager. I'm using `switcher` for that.

The problem is when I use backspace to delete the tabs in switcher it only put them invisible and when I reopened they shown again. I'd like to delete the history of switcher tabs, or don't shown them at all.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option (at least in current PhpStorm builds).

Accordingly to comments in [this ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137876) the original behaviour (where only active tabs were shown) is already restored. Not sure what PhpStorm build will have it .. but latest v9 EAP build 141.1619 does not have it yet (but v9 final should have it).

Comment: I hope in the future we have it !. Thanks for the reply tho